# Facebook User Long-lived access token could not be decrypted

Tags: encryption, facebook-access-token

I am facing with strange issue from Facebook user access token.

In details, i wanna get long-lived access token from my Facebook Apps and it return me 88 chars access token instead of 177 chars of correct access token (like before I use this way to get it), so I use it in my Java app using Facebook SDK and it always got error **"The access token could not be decrypted"**.
How to make it work, I am sure no typos or copy-paste missing in this case